# A simple question about a resolution of a conifers singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X$ be a conifold defined by the equation $xy-zw=0$ in $\mathbb{C}^4$ and $\tilde{X}$ its crepant resolution, which is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^1}}(-1)^{\oplus 2}$. Then there is a map $\tilde{X} \rightarrow X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where the first map is the resolution of the singularity and the second map is $(x,y,z,w)\mapsto xy$ (or equivalently $zw$).

My question is, what is the fiber of the map over $0 \in \mathbb{C}$? Does it depend on the crepant resolution (divisor we blow-up along) we take?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is your problem in describing the fiber?

Comment: I love the typo in the title. I now want to name all singularities after types of trees.